# Sequences and Orders

Tags: sequences-and-series

A sequence of 5 different cards is drawn from the standard poker deck. a) How many sequences will have exactly one Ace? b) How many sequences will have at least one Ace?  I was going to do (5 places)(12 cards)(12)(12)(12) = 103,680 for part a but I feel that I am wrong.  And b I am really lost on because I would do 12^5- 11^5 = 87781 but you only have 4 aces and not 5 so I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

To have exactly one ace, you need one ace, and four non-aces.  So choose the ace:  ${4 \choose 1}$.  Then choose the four non-aces:  ${48 \choose 4}$.  The total number of combinations is the product:  ${4 \choose 1}{48 \choose 4}$.  Now, to be clear, if you're looking for the total number of *sequences*, then order matters.  Each one of these combinations can be ordered in $5!$ ways.  So the number of sequences containing exactly one ace is:

$$S_1 = 5!{4 \choose 1}{48 \choose 4}.$$

Now, for *at least* one ace, you need to calculate the number of combinations for one, two, three, and four aces, add them up, and then multiply by $5!$ to get the number of sequences:

$$S_{\geq 1} = 5!\left[{4 \choose 1}{48 \choose 4} + {4 \choose 2}{48 \choose 3} + {4 \choose 3}{48 \choose 2} + {4 \choose 4}{48 \choose 1}\right].$$

Comment: Thanks John very helpful!